# How to fetch a column name

Tags: python, machine-learning

How can we apply conditions for a Dataset in python, specially applying those and want to fetch the column name as an output?
let's say the below one is the dataframe so my question is how can we retrieve a colname(let's say "name") as an output by applying conditions on this dataframe

```
            name  salary    jobDes
______________________________________
store1 |   daniel |   50k | datascientist
store2 | paladugu |   55k | datascientist
store3 |  theodor |   53k |  dataEngineer
```

fetch a column name as a result like let's say "name"

Comment: Is this `pandas` if so then edit the tags, please add a concrete example with code to explain what you want

Comment: `df.columns[0]`

Comment: If it is indeed pandas you can do this to apply conditions https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions/

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is named `df`, `df.columns` returns a list of all of the column names.

Answer (score 0):

**Elaborated**:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name':['daniel', 'paladugu', 'theodor'], 'jobDes':['datascientist', 'datascientist', 'dataEngineer']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)    
print(df['name'])    # just that easy
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0      daniel
1    paladugu
2     theodor
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using either pandas or dask, you should be able to get a list of column names with 
`df.columns`.

This means that if you wish to know what the first column is called you can index it (these start with 0 for the first element because python/c) as usual with `df.columns[0]` etc.

If you then wish to access all the data in it, you can use 
`df[df.columns[0]]` or the actual column name `df['name']`.